# how to improve twitter call times python

Tags: python, twitter

I wrote a code in python that calls twitter API 20 times:
10 times to twitter.users.search and 10 times to twitter.search.tweets.

I use time libary to check how much time each call take.
Average from 0.8 to 1 second, its take from 17 to 20 seconds to do all this calls.

anyone have any idea how to make it 2-3 seconds for all calls?

Comment: Have you tried multithreading or multiprocessing?

Comment: not yet, any suggestion in python?

Comment: First thing in my mind is: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor

Comment: not working, everytime fail.

Comment: Maybe you should include the code in the question, so that others could know what you have tried and figure out why you failed.